# How to request permission ? READ EXTERNAL STORAGE?

Tags: permissions, android-manifest, android-permissions, readfile, permission-denied

I am starting to develop a Android application for my usage, on my phone, and I am blocked with permissions. I need to read a GPX file.

I have made an Intent to pick my file with , but, onAtivityResult, when I try to open my file, nothing.
In my manifest file I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        ....
```

But when I look in the application parameters, on the phone, I don't have any permission requested
[screen copy app setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbbDD.jpg)

I also have adapted some code like this

```
    public boolean checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(final Context context) {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    showDialog("External storage", context,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void showDialog(final String msg, final Context context,
                           final String permission) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
        alertBuilder.setMessage(msg + " permission is necessary");
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                (dialog, which) -> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                        new String[]{permission},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    canReadExternalStorage = true;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "GET_ACCOUNTS Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                        grantResults);
        }
    }
```

but I always have the message "GET_ACCOUNTS Denied", it never ask me the permission

Some help would be welcome.